# Number of Likes and Dislikes to Star Rating system

Tags: average

I have a **5 star rating system** that outputs a recommendation.

A user inputs a rating based on a **Like** or **Dislike**.

*What I would like to know is how to convert the number of likes and dislikes into a number which can be put into a 5 star rating system?*

***An Example***:

Say if I have:

**172 Likes**

**101 Dislikes**

How would I then get then get the average of these likes and dislikes, to put into a 5 star system which resembles the number of likes compared to dislikes?

Comment: Are fractions of stars allowed or not?

Comment: What do you desire about the resultant system? Equal representation of each star rating? Simple average? Do you value any person's rating more than anothers? The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly straightforward way is to compute the fraction of likes as

$$
\text{fraction}_\text{likes} = \frac{\text{number}_\text{likes}}
                                    {\text{number}_\text{likes}+
                                     \text{number}_\text{dislikes}}
$$

and then if $\text{fraction}_\text{likes}$ is below $0.2$, that's one star; if it's at least $0.2$ but less than $0.4$, it's two stars; and so on.  More than $0.8$ is five stars.

ETA: If you allow for zero stars, you could break it down as follows: less than $0.1$, zero stars; at least $0.1$ but less than $0.3$, one star; and so on.  More than $0.9$ is five stars.

Comment: Okay brilliant, I think this is the best way. This is similar to the answer mentioned above, as you answered first I will mark you as correct.

Comment: That formula helps me a lot. I have structured the range for my project in following manner.

0 - 0.2 = 1 star

0.21 - 0.4 = 2 stars

0..41 - 0.6 = 3 stars

0.61 - 0.8 = 4 stars

0.81 - 1.0 = 5 stars

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the percentage of likes. Then have categories for the star amounts. For example

$1$ star : less than $25\%$

$2$ stars : $25\% - 45\%$

$3$ stars : $45\% - 65\%$

$4$ stars : $65\% - 85\%$

$5$ stars : more than $85\%$

Comment: This is a option but doesn't take dislikes into consideration so would put a bias on the likes? Say if there were more dislikes then likes this wouldn't be a fair representation?

Comment: @user3180997 Why? The percentage of likes tells exactly how many likes versus dislikes there are.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like: $$\frac{L}{L+D}\cdot 5$$, where $L$ is the number of likes and $D$ is the number of dislikes. This allows for fractions of stars. To get whole stars, just round the numbers either up or down, whichever you want.

Comment: Okay brilliant thank you, this got me some good numbers - thanks. Someone else answered below so I will mark that as correct, But this works as well. Thank you. I will mark up,

Answer (score 0):

I was stucked in a simmilar situation and finally came up with a preaty well performing function and have **tested for more than 30+** different usecases

**You can simply try this**

```
function calculateLikes(starCount,dislikeTotal,likesTotal){
   if(likesTotal==0 || starCount==0) return 0;
  return ((starCount-(dislikeTotal/(likesTotal/starCount))).toFixed(1));
}
```

Here:

1. starCount      is total no. of Stars
2. dislikeTotal   is total no. of Dislikes
3. likesTotal     is total no. of Likes

**And using the function as below**

5 star rating system

```
  console.log(calculateLikes(5,101,172));
```

**Output :-**  2.1

10 star rating system

```
  console.log(calculateLikes(10,101,172));
```

**Output :-**  4.1

Atleast that works well as per my expectations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).